# Why is postsharp causing a web project to fail on publish?

Tags: c#, postsharp

In version 4.2.27 of postsharp publishing a web project works correct.

When the postsharp nuget package is upgraded to > 4.2.28 the publish fails. It fails when trying to run TransformWebConfigCore in Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets. The error

> Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1483,5): Error : Could not open
>   Source file: Could not find file '[Project
>   Location]\Web.config;web.config'.

Comment: Do you use webconfig transforms? Also you couldcheck in the csproj file if The upgrade went successfull by checking if there are any references to 4.2.27

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PostSharp 4.2.28 adds Web.config to `Content` MSBuild ItemGroup automatically. It is the reason why you see web.config twice in the error message:

> Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1483,5): Error : Could not open
>   Source file: Could not find file '[Project
>   Location]\**Web.config**;**web.config**'.

If your csproj contains this element:

```
<Content Include="Web.config" />
```

Change `Content` to `None`:

```
<None Include="Web.config" />
```

Make sure that the web.config file is included after publishing your web project.

Comment: is there any reference to the PostSharp Documentation regarding your comment "PostSharp 4.2.28 ..."? The solution works but I am not confident that I fully understand the rationale. IMO, it seems rather hackish (I almost reinstalled my build server because of this error)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It was driving me crazy trying to find out the solution. I also noticed my SlowCheetah configs weren't working in VS, wonder if Postsharp is responsible for it.